# Can we provide a logging directory for a project in Rundeck?

Tags: rundeck

I have several projects with multiple cron jobs scheduled in each on a Linux machine configured with Rundeck. I wanted to know if there is a simpler logging configuration that could be added so that all logs belonging to crons of one project are available in a common directory. 

For instance, project A contains 3 scheduled crons A1, A2 and A3.
A possibility of logging in a common directory would be to do add the log location to the cron command individually

```
bash testA1.sh>/logs/A/logA1.log
bash testA2.sh>/logs/A/logA2.log
bash testA3.sh>/logs/A/logA3.log
```

I wanted to know if there is a configuration for the project level `A` where I could add the parent directory for logging as `/logs/A` I could then change the commands as

```
bash testA1.sh>logA1.log
bash testA2.sh>logA2.log
bash testA3.sh>logA3.log
```

Additionally, can the logging file be provided in the cron configuration without specifying `>{log_file_name}.log` in the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using logging plugin you can do that.

For example, you can configure a [log plugin](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/plugins/configuring.html#logging) (for example [s3/minio plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-s3-log-plugin)) at project level (setting at project.properties file)-

```
project.plugin.ExecutionFileStorage.org.rundeck.amazon-s3.path=/common/path/logs/${job.project}/${job.execid}.log
```

As you see, you can use job/project context variables with your custom path/filenames.

[Check](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-s3-log-plugin#configuration) the full configuration documentation.

Tip: you can use s3 log plugin with [Minio](https://min.io/) locally without problems.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, but is there any way to do this without the S3 plugin? Can I not directly give the path for a logging folder in the project configs?